# OpenCL runtime library for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: runtime, shared-libraries, opencl, ubuntu-14.04

I need to use OpenCL library for NVidia GPU in a machine but I can not install globally (I am not the super user), and so I need runtime library which can be used locally. I found in NVidia [webpage](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux)
the OpenCL library for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 but not 14.04 and it should be install using command

```
$ sudo sh cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run
```

SO anyone knows where I can find OpenCL library for Ubuntu 14.04 and how to use it locally.

Comment: You can't. The OpenCL library is part of the driver, not the toolkit

Comment: @talonmies What did you mean by "part of the driver". It is, as I know, a shared library can used to communicated with GPUs/CPUs.

Comment: The library is part of the driver package and is distributed with the driver, not the CUDA toolkit.

Comment: Also, be aware that NVidia try to push for it private CUDA technology, and even the newest graphic card are currently limited to the deprecated version 1.2
So if you really want to explore OpenCL (v2 + ), NVidia is not a good choice.

Comment: By chance, are you asking about the [OpenCL ICD Loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader)? This is what searches your device for all compatible OpenCL device drivers.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for your point. I thought I should explicitly install OpenCL library for NVidia GPU, like intel CPU. But I realized it is implicitly (optional) install while the driver of the NVidia (and CUDA) is installed. No I only need to find where header file located.